# Finding non-trivial functions $f(x)$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)=\int_{0}^1f(x)dx$

Tags: integration, summation

It is known that Atle Selberg found the following expression when he was 14 years old :
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-n}=\int_{0}^1x^{-x}dx.$$

Then, here is my question.

**Question** : Find the other non-trivial functions $f(x)$ such that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)=\int_{0}^1f(x)dx.\ \ \ \cdots(\star)$$

**Motivation** : I found the followings:

Let $m$ be a natural number. Let us define a function $f(x)$ for $a\gt0$ as
$$f(x)=\frac1{(x+a)^m}-\frac1{(x+a+1)^m}\ \ \ (x\ge 0).$$
I'm going to prove that for any $m\in\mathbb N$ there exists only one $a\gt 0$ such that $f(x)$ satisfies $(\star)$.

*1.* The $m=1$ case.

We get
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac1{n+a}-\frac1{n+a+1}\right)=\frac1{a+1},$$
$$\int_{0}^1f(x)dx=[\log(x+a)-\log(x+a+1)]_0^1=-\log\left(1-\left(\frac1{a+1}\right)^2\right).$$

Hence, if there exist $0\lt u_0\lt 1$ such that $$u_0=-\log(1-{u_0}^2),$$then $f(x)$ satisfies $(\star)$ when $a=a_0={u_0}^{-1}-1$.

In fact, we find that there exists only one such $u_0$ by observing 
$$G(u)=-\log(1-u^2)-u\ \ (0\lt u\lt 1).$$

*2.* The $m\ge 2$ case.

We get 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)=\frac1{(a+1)^m},$$
$$\int_{0}^1f(x)dx=\frac1{m-1}\left\{\frac1{a^{m-1}}-\frac2{(a+1)^{m-1}}+\frac1{(a+2)^{m-1}}\right\}.$$

Hence, let's prove that there exist $a\gt0$ such that
$$\frac1{(a+1)^m}=\frac1{m-1}\left\{\frac1{a^{m-1}}-\frac2{(a+1)^{m-1}}+\frac1{(a+2)^{m-1}}\right\}\ \ \ \ \cdots(\star\star)$$
Letting
$$h_m(a)=\frac{(a+1)^m}{a^{m-1}}+\frac{(a+1)^{m}}{(a+2)^{m-1}}-2(a+1)-(m-1),$$
then we know that 
$$(\star\star)\iff h_m(a)=0.$$

However, getting
$$\begin{align}
h_m(a) & = \frac{(a+1)^{m}}{a^{m-1}}+\frac{((a+2)-1)^m}{(a+2)^{m-1}}-2(a+1)-(m-1) \\
 & = \frac1{a^{m-1}}\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}a^{m-k}+\frac1{(a+2)^{m-1}}\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}(-1)^k(a+2)^{m-k}-2(a+1)-(m-1) \\ 
 & = -(m-1)+\sum_{k=2}^m\binom{m}{k}\left\{\frac1{a^{k-1}}+\frac{(-1)^k}{(a+2)^{k-1}}\right\}
\end{align}$$
tells us
$$\lim_{a\to +0}h_m(a)=+\infty, \lim_{a\to +\infty}h_m(a)=-(m-1)\lt 0,$$
$$h_m^{\prime}(a)=-\sum_{k=2}^m\binom{m}{k}(k-1)\left\{\frac1{a^k}+\frac{(-1)^k}{(a+2)^k}\right\}\lt0.$$

Here, note that 
$$\frac1{a^k}+\frac{(-1)^k}{(a+2)^k}\gt 0.$$

Hence, we know that there exists only one $a\gt 0$ such that $h_m(a)=0.$ Now the proof is completed.

By the way, we know $a=\sqrt2$ for $m=2$.

I've been looking for the other functions, but I cannot find any other function. Can anyone help?

Comment: I wonder if you are not viewing "function" as something which can be written down with a single algebraic formula valid at every point. It is a long time since mathematicians stopped doing it.

Comment: Still an interesting question though. He who finds the most general function wins.

Comment: You'll want to restrict the class of functions to those that are defined by some simple formula (and I doubt there's a good way of doing it). Otherwise you impose just one equation on the huge function space -- an obviously underdetermined system.

Comment: I asked a question about this a while ago: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69841/for-which-f-does-sum-n-0-infty-fa-1-a-kn-int-0-infty and at present I think you ought be looking at the Abel-Plana summation formula: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula

Comment: I knew that there are a lot of 'functions' which satisfy this conditions, but I would like to know some 'interesting' functions(Of course, this is subjective). Anyway, Vedran's answer is absolutely correct. So, my question has been already answered. (Sadly, I think it seems impossible to make this question more interesting. I'll wait for another answer for a while.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more of a comment, but too long to put there.

Keep in mind that the value of a function at isolated points does not affect its integral. So, take any integrable function $f: [0,1\rangle \to \mathbb{R}$, and let $I := \int_0^1 f(x) dx$. Now, expand the deinfition of $f$:

\begin{align*}
f(1) &:= I, \\
f(n) &:= 0, \quad n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{1\}, \\
f(x) &:= \text{anything you want}, \quad x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus ([0,1 \rangle \cup \mathbb{N}).
\end{align*}

Even if you want a continuous function, you can still define it by starting from $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, and then you set its values outside of $[0,1]$, so that
\begin{align*}
f(2) &:= I - f(1), \\
f(n) &:= 0, \quad n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{1\}, \\
f(x) &:= \text{anything you want}, \quad x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus ([0,1 \rangle \cup \mathbb{N}).
\end{align*}

You can always do this (and in a huge number of ways) while preserving the continuity of your function.

Comment: Oh, You are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}J_0(nx)J_0(ny)J_0(nz)-\int_0^{\infty}J_0(ux)J_0(uy)J_0(uz)du=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: I suspect this example doesn't satisfy the condition.